# Looking for shapefiles describing Katmai National Park in Alaska

Tags: geospatial

As detailed as possible - including streams, lakes, rivers, trails, and elevation changes.

Answer (score 2):

In data.gov, you can find shapefiles and other data on national parks. Here's a link to the datasets for Katmai National Park

https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/national-park-boundariesf0a4c

As a little extra, here's a link to the National Park Service's webpage for the park. No shapefiles, but has photos and live webcams:

http://www.nps.gov/katm/learn/photosmultimedia/webcams.htm

This is a link to Alaska State Geo-Spatial Data Clearinghouse:

http://www.asgdc.state.ak.us/

This is a link to Alaska Division of Geological & Geophysical Surveys. Anything you can't find otherwise, you probably can get by contacting them.

http://dggs.alaska.gov/

nps search has over 2000 hits for Katmai, although not sure how many are shapefiles
https://irma.nps.gov/App/

Comment: Thanks albert! I found this link as well https://irma.nps.gov/App/Reference/Profile/1048776